# How to construct (with straightedge and compass) this diagram with four circles and two chords?

Tags: circles, geometric-construction, golden-ratio

Inspired by [this Sangaku-style question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4708430/398708) about a constellation of circles, I've come up with the following question.

> How can we construct, with straightedge and compass, the following diagram?

[image]

Description: In a (large) circle, two equal length chords share a point on the circle. In each of the two segments thus formed, a largest possible circle is inscribed. A third circle touches the large circle and both chords. The three inscribed circles are of equall radii.

The ratio of the large circle's radii to the smaller circles' radii is $\phi+1$, where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ is the golden ratio ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4708473/398708)).

If we construct the chords, then the circles are easy to draw. But how can we construct the chords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio of the smaller circle to the larger circle is $$\frac{1}{\phi+1}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

If you decide on the radius of the larger circle first, say $1$ unit, then draw a straight line of length $3$ units.

Take a point $2$ units from one end of the line, and construct a perpendicular from there of length $1$ unit to make a right-angled triangle whose hypotenuse is $\sqrt{5}$. Mark off the length $\sqrt{5}$ from one end of the first line. Bisect the remaining length of that line to make a length of $$\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Now that you have the smaller radius you can draw the upper circle first, then the chords, and finally the two side circles, a process which should be fairly routine.